# TableView: Probably a simple error

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im working with a table view, and im wondering why my if-statement is false.
Probably a really simple error. I have debugged and I saw that 'message' contained the value of the tableview cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSString *apple = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Apple"];
if(apple == message)
.....
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing objects. You'll want to use the following code instead:

```
if ([apple isEqualToString:message]) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, that simple, you are comparing addresses of two different variables, they are not the same numbers for sure :) For the content comparison you use

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString
```

Please, read the NSString [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) carefully, you'll also might want to find some literature about the c language fundamental.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you just post the code? I don't really understand! Yeah, i think so to, need to learn some basics :) 

Thanks

Comment: the code Reed Olsen posted is perfectly correct, you are comparing the content of the NSString object at apple address with the content of NSString object at message address, the "*" when you are declaring a new variable means the pointer to the object of the class type will be created. You can find a lot information about the pointers and memory management in general. Will correct the answer a little adding a full method signature there (you should really try to find some additional info if the "method signature" doesn't ring a bell, but that's ok, we've all started one day :) )

Answer (score 0):

In your case `message` is a pointer address to the `NSString` object in memory. When you do `==` you are comparing the addresses of the pointers not the content of the string. To compare the contents of the actual `NSString` objects you need to use the appropriate method `isEqualToString:`.

In the following example I have created two strings and shown they have the same content but different pointer addresses. The `%p` in the `NSLog()` prints the pointer address

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"];
NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"];

NSLog(@"(%p == %p)      => %d", string1, string2, string1 == string2);
NSLog(@"[string1 isEqualToString:string2] => %d", [string1 isEqualToString:string2]);

=> 2012-03-14 22:55:07.395 Untitled[2797:707] (0x1099146c0 == 0x109914870)      => 0
=> 2012-03-14 22:55:07.398 Untitled[2797:707] [string1 isEqualToString:string2] => 1
```